# Add Hamburger in Navigation Bar

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXwNF.png)I'm trying to add a hamburger slide out in my navigation bar. I would like it to slide out to the right. We're using elementor in WP. Has anyone done this before? I cannot figure out a way to do this where it will stick.

This is the code I want to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    
<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
}
</script>
    
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f4ee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="elementor-menu-toggle">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">xxxxxx</a>
    <a href="#">xxxxxx</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I'm getting back in the console as my class:

```
.elementor-84 .elementor-element.elementor-element-461994e > .elementor-widget-container {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-widget-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.ob-has-background-overlay > .elementor-widget-container {
    position: relative;
}

.elementor-element .elementor-widget-container {
    transition: background .3s,border .3s,border-radius .3s,box-shadow .3s,transform var(--e-transform-transition-duration,.4s);
}
.elementor *, .elementor :after, .elementor :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

so I just need help figuring out which class I use, or if I'm missing something? I did try adjusting the css in the advanced widget for the nav bar, but after hitting update it does not stick.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Elementor Pro to create the header, you can use the responsive options in the advanced tab.
You could create a section only visible on desktop with the double menu and then a second section only visible in mobile with one single menu.

See more here. [Responsive editing for mobile and tablets](https://elementor.com/help/mobile-editing/)